# I expect Jay will come, so I'll be disappointed if he does/will not

Tags: sentence-construction, to-infinitive, if

> I expect Jay **will** come, so I'll be disappointed if he **does/will** not.
>
> I expect Jay **to** come, so I'll be disappointed if he **does/will** not.

Do the alternatives, **doesn't** and **won't**, have the same meaning in both sentences?

Comment: You should note that *...if he **will** not* (or semantically equivalent contracted *...if he **won't***) is idiomatically unlikely in the cited context. But if it ***is*** used, the implication is that Jay *specifically **refused** to come* (deliberately, as "an act of will", rather than because his car broke down or something). On the other hand, *...if he doesn't* carries no particular implications for *why* he might not arrive, or whether he actually *wants* to come.

Comment: What Fumble said above, and to add that in this case, the grammar of the first clause doesn't have any effect on what's grammatical in the second clause as they have nearly identical meanings.

Answer (score 1):

English speakers rarely use *will* after "if", so the normal form would be *if he doesn't* (or *does not*).

*Will* is used in an "if" clause only if there is a special sense: either *be willing to*, or *insist on* (the latter generally with a connotation of annoyance in the speaker).

So *I'll be disappointed if he won't* means something more than "if it happens that he doesn't": it implies something like "if he refuses to".